# Removing editor tags with Visual Studio SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tags, visual-studio-sdk

Is it possible to remove already applied editor tags? I only [found a way to add new tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd885244.aspx), but this doesn't allow me to override or remove existing tags.

As a sidenote, my scenario is the following: I'm trying to add a new keyword to the C# language. My first step is to prevent the keyword from being indicated as an error by ReSharper. I believe ReSharper added an `ErrorTag` on the invalid keyword, which is the one I am trying to remove/override.

Comment: add a new keyword to the language?  How is that possible?

Comment: @A.R.: Perhaps not. :) The idea is to intercept the building event and translate the source code before it is compiled, adjust it and compile the adjusted source code.

Comment: hmmm... interesting.  Dangerous, but very interesting.  Have you looked into something like PostSharp and its like? (http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) It is in the same vein, but probably not exactly what you are looking for.  At any rate, I love a good technical challenge, so let me know how it goes.

Comment: @A.R.: Yup, I use PostSharp. As far as I know PostSharp doesn't adjust the actual source code, but the MSIL code, so it works at a later stage. The idea of this approach would be to adjust it even earlier, something like a very advanced macro.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't quite think that it was going to do the trick.  Rats.  What about a 'Domain Specific Language'?  That is probably getting even further from the simple use of a keyword, but is a bit closer to what you are going for.

Comment: @A.R.: Sounds about the thing I am trying to achieve, but I would need a way to 'extend' from C# and add new keywords on top of that. Have looked shortly at [language services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165099%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) in the VS SDK but I'm not sure whether this allows extending a language.

Comment: Yeah, that is not for 'extending' languages at all.  I think the rule of thumb is that the languages and their syntax are fixed / immutable so other developer can read your code, compiler stuff, etc.  I think you are going to have to come up with something very tricky in the end to achieve your goal.  Maybe a snippet is the best option?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that because editor tags are setup via Attributes on classes, you won't be able to remove tags from extensions that you own, in this case ReSharper.  I think that if you want to achieve your described goal you are just going to have to deal with the error indications.

From MSDN:

```
[Export(typeof(ITaggerProvider))]
[ContentType("text")]
[TagType(typeof(TestTag))]
internal class TestTaggerProvider : ITaggerProvider
```

You can see the 'TagType' attribute on the class 'TestTaggerProvider' that actual does the tagging within the IDE.

Comment: Attributes on classes? Tags are applied on spans of text.

Comment: Yes, but you need an attribute on the class, in the extension that provides the tag to be applied to the text.

Comment: I can't prevent ReSharper from adding those tags no, unless I disable ReSharper of course. I believe (haven't tried yet) I can at least find the tags which ReSharper added using [ITagAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd868079.aspx). If I would have a way to remove them ... :)